# I can't bring single data

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ads.product_id,
        products.imageversion,
        ads.id,
        ads.stock,
        ads.miad,
        ads.level_of_sales,
        products.NAME,
        ads.price,
        b2b_users.username,
        b2b_users.id AS userid,
        products.image 
    FROM
        ads
        JOIN product_categories ON ads.product_id = product_categories.product_id
        JOIN b2b_users ON ads.uid = b2b_users.id
        JOIN products ON ads.product_id = products.id 
    WHERE
        (
            product_categories.category_id LIKE '1092083006%' 
            AND ads.STATUS = '1' 
            AND b2b_users.ads_status = '1' 
            AND ads.stock > 0 
            AND ads.banned = 0 
        ) 
    GROUP BY
        ads.product_id 
    ORDER BY
        ads.price ASC 
    ) T1 
ORDER BY
    rand( 1229538830 ) 
    LIMIT 24 OFFSET 0
```

Hello there,

The transaction I want to do is when I use min price, low cost data comes. But username is not the same ones

thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, I must point out that `ORDR BY rand( 1229538830 )`  may not be doing what you expect.  While that tives a random ordering, it gives you the *same* ordering.  You probably want simply `ORDER BY RAND()`, which gives a random ordering, but a different subset (assuming `LIMIT 24`) of rows each time.

Second, `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are mostly redundant.  `GROUP BY` is mostly used for doing aggregates such as `COUNT(*)` or `SUM(qty)`.  `DISTINCT` is probably what you want.

Third, cf "only full group by".  Old versions of MySQL let you get away with grouping by a column on which not everything depended.  Perhaps this works with `ads.product_id`; I can't be sure.

Now, back to your question.  Alas, I don't understand the question.  What is the intent of the 3 columns?  Were they failed attempts at doing something?  Suggest you provide a small set of data and point out what you would like the result to be.  (And leave out the columns that are not pertinent to the question.)